# Is there a way to print the current sequence of command keys in normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode

Sometimes I get lost in normal mode. Is there a way to have vim/vi print the last keys pressed, perhaps at the top/bottom of the screen.

For example, in normal mode I may enter the command `22gg` to go to line 22.

It is a somewhat trivial example, however I may accidentally type `222gg`. I would like to be able to see what I enter into normal mode somehow. Is this possible or is there a plugin for this?

Edit: The linked question doesn't seem to resolve the problem

I've followed the link but it isn't working.

Comment: What did you do and how is "not working"? It works fine for the rest of us.

Comment: Did you mean `set showcmd` in your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Yeah I have `set showcmd` but it doesn't appear to do anything?